# what is the difference between gtags-mode and ggtags-mode

Tags: gtags

In my emacs (24.5.1) I have both and I'm not sure which is what. ggtags was installed through `list-packages` from melpa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC `gtags-mode` ships as part of GNU Global and gives a basic set of commands and key bindings for using Global.  [`ggtags`](https://github.com/leoliu/ggtags) does much the same thing but is a much more comprehensive package with way more features.  I initially found some of the ggtags keybindings to be a little confusing (especially after doing a find tag operation) but in the long run it's probably going to be a better solution than plain `gtags-mode`.